# Lateral bipedal centaur

Tags: science-based, evolution, aliens, anatomy

I keep finding createures that are centaurs but with only two legs one behind the other.

How or why would this evolve? A low gravity environment is the first thing to come to mind, but also the only thing to come to mind. Would this somehow make it more agile or is it just impractical art? And if you have any ideas about those weird wings that would be a bonus.

Comment: I had some doubts with the watermark, but after searching you didn't seem to have respected the author's right on Selkra's picture : They explicitly asked to "[not use, edit or repost this art anywhere](https://www.deviantart.com/selkra/art/Kwiip-Desert-Environment-873856896)". Besides, since the picture's description on deviant art includes already some worldbuilding, it's more 3rd party than actual worldbuilding :/.

Comment: VTC: (a) Asking how any creature can evolve is clearly a violation of the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule. (b) Asking how an obviously impossible-to-evolve creature can evolve is opinion-based, hypothetical, and inspecific (violating rules in [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). (c) Worst of all, finding someone's art online and asking how it can be represented in Real Life on a site that's dedicated to helping you create an imaginary world sounds a lot like "mindless social fun" ([help/dont-ask]).

Comment: And after following the link provided by @Tortliena, I've removed the images that are an obvious and clear violation of copyright. *Thou shalt not violate copyright on Stack Exchange.* I'm sure that rule is around here somewhere... probably in the Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vulnerable, not balanced**

Poor creature. What if it falls over to the side ? How would it get up again ? This animal won't *evolve*,  its predecessors, that is rudimentary versions with a similar building plan would die out before a mature, mammal-like species like you show would ever appear.

**Strong arms**

yes, these could allow it to regain balance somehow. But a lot of energy is wasted developing arms strong enough to do that. I still don't believe this creature would exist anywhere

**Summary**

probably not